# Managing permissions on RESTful service

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, permissions

I am working on an SPA application using angularjs and Web API. I've been working on setting up user permissions for the resources on the api.

Since the api is a RESTful service, I'm not sure the best practice to store/retrieving the permissions. The permissions in my application can change somewhat frequently, as users have different permissions for different companies they belong to. The user can change their company on the fly in the application.

The way I have is solved currently, is when the user logs in, the application stores a claim for every permission the user has, for all companies. The claim is stored with permission name and company id concatenated together. Then I have an attribute that accepts a permission name. Then I concatenate that name with the selected company id in the app and see if it exists in the claims. If so, they have access.

Another option I see is to only store only pertinent user info in claims (user id, name). Then do a lookup every time I need roles or permissions. A drawback here is there will be a lot of traffic since I need that information on almost every api request. Also, since I have the authentication and resource server separated, it's not a simple lookup. I'd have to go over http to get the data.

Are these my only options or is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Bearer Tokens to solve this problem.  A bearer token is essentially an encrypted JSON string, that can contain all of the claims for a user.  In your case, I recommend a having separate claim for every company/permission combination.

Bearer tokens are created on the server, and the exact technique you would use to generate one depends on the server technology/framework you are using.

Your SPA will send the bearer token with every request (take a look at $HttpInterceptor service to accomplish this).  At the server, your service will decrypt the token, and use the claims information therein to verify whether or not the user has permissions for the given endpoint.

Comment: Thanks Byron for the post. I guess I should've mentioned that the permissions on the claims are stored using bearer tokens. It's good to hear you recommend the route I went.